# Apply styles in a PrimeNG dialog

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm having troubles trying to apply styles in a PrimeNG dialog.

I have a component which have a PrimeNG dialog:

```
<p-dialog header="Filters" [(visible)]="display" width="1000" height="1000" modal="modal">
...
</p-dialog>
```

I also have a scss file where I have the styles of the component. The background-color of the dialog is transparent but I want to set it to white. So I've tried to apply the style in different ways in my scss file:

```
.ui-dialog {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Adding styleClass to the dialog and trying to apply styles to it:

```
<p-dialog styleClass="dialog-filters" header="Filters" [(visible)]="display" width="1000" height="1000" modal="modal">

.dialog-filters {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

None of them works. Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

For a style argument you should use use []. So when you want to apply inline-style to p-dialog that would be for example `<p-dialog [style]="{'margin-left':'80px', 'margin-right':'80px'}"></p-dialog>`.

I must admit I very confused myself when primeng requires [], nothing or [()], at least when looking at their website, which is not frequently updated. So  you better just take a look into their source code on github.

Answer (score 3):

use the following css method

```
:host ::ng-deep .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar{
    background: tomato; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `styleClass` property of `p-dialog` as below,

```
<p-dialog header="Title" [(visible)]="display" modal="modal" width="300" styleClass="active" >
....
```

Styles in css file will be as

```
.active{
  background-color:red
}
```

Alternatively, if you are using `ui-dialog` classes, you should be using them in hierarchy as below

```
p-dialog .ui-dialog {
  background-color: red;
}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/ThvoNxYZwvpCJeNUnd8u?p=preview)** contains both methods

Comment: how do I do this conditionally as with ngClass?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for modifying an existing class from html.

```
 <p-confirmDialog
                header="Confirmation"
                appendTo="body"
                width="425"
                icon="pi pi-exclamation-triangle"
                >
<style type="text/css">
            .ui-widget-overlay.ui-dialog-mask {
               opacity: 0 !important;
            }
</style>

 </p-confirmDialog>
```

Also make sure to set: encapsulation value

```
@Component({
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Comment: It's also better to add some explanations.

Comment: what do you mean that??

Answer (score 1):

"primeng": "^14.1.2",

in styles.scss

```
.p-dialog .p-dialog-header {
  background: red;
  color: #333333;

}

.p-dialog .p-dialog-content {
  background: red;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 1rem;
}


.p-dialog .p-dialog-footer {
  background: red;
  color: #333333;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

@kishor's solution worked for me. Also if you want to apply styles specifically to your dialog box then you can assign it a class using styleClass and use that class in CSS.

`<p-dialog  position="center" modal="true" styleClass="customDialog"> ... </p-dialog>`

```
// DIALOG BOX
:host {
    ::ng-deep .customDialog {
        background-color: white !important;
        width: 92vw !important;
        box-shadow: 0px 20px 20px #D8DDE680;
        border: 1px solid rgb(231, 231, 231);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update for PrimeNg 12:**
All the mentioned solutions did not do anything for me or produced weird outcomes.

I had to use styleClass="custom-dialog" on the p-dialog and create the .custom-dialog in my **styles.scss** file like this:

```
.custom-dialog { 
max-width: 90%;                     
border: 6px solid white !important;
border-radius:18px !important;
}
```

To overwrite anything but the width and height property you need to use !important.